# Update custom cascading select field in JIRA via suds

Tags: jira, suds, python-2.7

Using JIRA version 4.2.  With Python 2.7 and suds 0.4, how can I update an issue's custom cascading select's field (both parent and child)?

There is a [SOAPpy example](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Creating+a+SOAP+Client) available under "Python (SOAPPy) client".
I was [unable to perform](https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/browse/JCLIMD-9) this type of update using the [Python JIRA CLI](https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/browse/JCLIMD).

Example:
When updating the cascading select custom child of parent field, customfield_10, one would want to update the field customfield_10_1.

**Update**

Code to display cascading field's original value:

```
issue = client.service.getIssue(auth, "NAHLP-33515")
for f in fields:
    if f['customfieldId'] == 'customfield_10050' or f['customfieldId'] == 'customfield_10050_1':
        print f
```

This results in:

```
(RemoteCustomFieldValue){
   customfieldId = "customfield_10050"
   key = None
   values[] =
      "10981",
 }
```

After manually setting the cascading field's child, the above code results in:

```
(RemoteCustomFieldValue){
   customfieldId = "customfield_10050"
   key = None
   values[] =
      "10981",
 }
(RemoteCustomFieldValue){
   customfieldId = "customfield_10050"
   key = "1"
   values[] =
      "11560",
 }
```

**The above values is what I hope to achieve via suds**.

Note the *key = "1"* field.  The key value designates that this object is the child of customfield_10050.
[Documentation reference](http://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/rpc-jira-plugin/latest/com/atlassian/jira/rpc/soap/beans/RemoteCustomFieldValue.html):
*parentKey - Used for multi-dimensional custom fields such as Cascading select lists. Null in other cases*

Let's try sending a key field value:

```
client.service.updateIssue(auth, "NAHLP-33515", [
                           {"id":"customfield_10050", "values":["10981"]},
                           {"id":"customfield_10050_1", "key":"1", "values":["11560"]}
                           ])
```

This results in an error because the [updateIssue](http://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/rpc-jira-plugin/latest/com/atlassian/jira/rpc/soap/JiraSoapService.html#updateIssue%28java.lang.String%2C%20java.lang.String%2C%20com.atlassian.jira.rpc.soap.beans.RemoteFieldValue%5B%5D%29) accepts a [RemoteFieldValue](http://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/rpc-jira-plugin/latest/com/atlassian/jira/rpc/soap/beans/RemoteFieldValue.html)[] parameter, not a [RemoteCustomFieldValue](http://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/rpc-jira-plugin/latest/com/atlassian/jira/rpc/soap/beans/RemoteCustomFieldValue.html)[] parameter ([thanks Matt Doar](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Creating+a+SOAP+Client?focusedCommentId=232555101#comment-232555101)):

```
suds.TypeNotFound: Type not found: 'key'
```

So how do we pass a RemoteCustomFieldValue parameter to update an issue?

**Update 2, mdoar's answer**

Ran following code via suds:

```
client.service.updateIssue(auth, "NAHLP-33515", [
                           {"id":"customfield_10050", "values":["10981"]},
                           {"id":"customfield_10050_1", "values":["11560"]}
                           ])`
```

After value:

```
(RemoteCustomFieldValue){
   customfieldId = "customfield_10050"
   key = None
   values[] =
      "10981",
 }
```

Unfortunately, this does not update the child of customfield_10050. Verified manually.

**Resolution:**

Thank you mdoar!  To update a parent and child of a cascading select field, use the colon (':') to designate the child filed.

**Working example:**

```
client.service.updateIssue(auth, "NAHLP-33515", [
                           {"id":"customfield_10050", "values":["10981"]},
                           {"id":"customfield_10050:1", "values":["11560"]}
                           ])
```